# Adding a new language to PowerPoint list of subtitle languages

Tags: office365, powerpoint, subtitle, presentation, google-apps-for-education

I use the translated subtitle option for teaching foreign students. Pashto is listed as an available language on MS Office, but is not featured on the pull down list of subtitle languages on Powerpoint. Can I manually add it?

I have tried adding a language and have checked that it is an available language - which it appears to be

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows

1. Go to settings.
2. Type language in search bar.
3. Click on Add Language.
   [image]
4. Select pashto from the list and click next.
5. Then open powerpoint. Go to File tab and click on options.
6. Go to language tab.
   [image]

6. Select and add pashto from the list.